# How to submit data programitacaly to the Activiti BPM process

Tags: java, activiti, business-process-management

I'm using activiti BPM and I want to use to run my bpm process without Activiti explore. Simply I have user task with one form variable. I need help to assign value for that task using java.
Here is my code:

```
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String filename = "E:/Activiti/STS_workspace/Test/src/main/resources/diagrams/FinancialReportProcess.bpmn";

    ActivitiRule activitiRule = new ActivitiRule();

    // Create Activiti process engine
      ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration
        .createStandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration()
        .setDatabaseType("postgres")
        .setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testActiviti")
        .setJdbcDriver("org.postgresql.Driver")
        .setJdbcUsername("postgres")
        .setJdbcPassword("postgres")
        .setDatabaseSchemaUpdate("true")
        .buildProcessEngine();

      // Get Activiti services
      RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
      RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();

      // Deploy the process definition
      repositoryService.createDeployment()
        .addInputStream("financialReport.bpmn20.xml", new FileInputStream(filename)).deploy();

      // Start a process instance
        String procId = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("financialReport").getId();

        FormService formService = processEngine.getFormService();

        Map<String, String> formProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
        formProperties.put("name", "activiti rocks!");


        // Get the first task
        TaskService taskService = processEngine.getTaskService();

        List<Task> tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskCandidateGroup("accountancy").list();
        for (Task task : tasks) {

          System.out.println("Following task is available for accountancy group: " + task.getName());

          TaskFormData taskFormData = formService.getTaskFormData(task.getId());

          List<FormProperty> listFormProperty = taskFormData.getFormProperties();

          for(FormProperty formProperty : listFormProperty){
                 System.out.println(task.getId()+":"+task.getName()+"id:"+formProperty.getId());
                 System.out.println(task.getId()+":"+task.getName()+"name:"+formProperty.getName());
                 System.out.println(task.getId()+":"+task.getName()+"type:"+formProperty.getType().getName());
                 System.out.println(task.getId()+":"+task.getName()+"value:"+formProperty.getValue());

              }

          System.out.println("task is "+task.getId()+":"+task.getName()+":"+task.getAssignee()+":"+task.getDescription());
        }



}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so Here is an example of a simple process Check the part with this comment on `THIS IS THE PART YOU ARE INTERESTED IN I THINK`

```
//Create the proces variables
     Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         variables.put("requester", userRequestingForAbsence); //User who wants timeOff
         variables.put("dateFrom", new Date(2015, 10, 10));
         variables.put("dateTo", new Date(2015, 11, 11));
         variables.put("group", groupDto);
         variables.put("organization", orgDto.getOrganizationId());
         variables.put("candidateApprover", p.getUserId());

         //Create the process instance
//Im using org.activiti.engine.RuntimeService
         ProcessInstance pi = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("myProcess", String.valueOf(orgDto.getOrganizationId()),variables);
         //Create Process Instance
         Assert.assertNotNull(pi);

         //Check inbox for approver 
         Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery()
                 ))
                   // .taskCandidateGroup(String.valueOf(orgDto.getOrganizationId()))
                    .taskAssignee(String.valueOf(p.getUserId()))
                    .singleResult();

         Assert.assertEquals("RequestAproval", task.getName());


         //Approver Completes ApprovalRequest and we add additional values THIS IS THE PART YOU ARE INTERESTED IN I THINK

         Map<String, Object> userTaskVariables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         userTaskVariables.put("requestAccepted", true);
         userTaskVariables.put("approver",approver);

         //Complete Task
         taskService.complete(task.getId(),userTaskVariables);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: appreciate your answer. lets keep this simple.. i have simple bpm process with two user task and one form variable for each process.(variable clientName).   i want to submit client name to the process. i have search about submitTaskFormData like that method. but i have no idea. please give me simple example..

Comment: You don't need forms to submit the client name to the process. you can just add them to the process when you complete the task as im doing in the example. Do you need build-in form rendering ?

Comment: could you please sir can you give me a simple login example using activiti?

Comment: Take a look at this repos. its a good place to start if you want to start with examples https://github.com/jbarrez